# Regex for string neither preceded nor followed by any alphabet character

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have these keywords:

1. top
2. top-blue
3. blue-top
4. my top
5. light-grn-top
6. top-cotton
7. laptop
8. laptop-glossy
9. green top 0192
10. desktop 45WAI
11. topbest

**(updated condition)**

**12. village_top1993**

Required matches are : top, top-blue, blue-top, my top, light-grn-top, top-cotton, green top 0192, **village_top1993**

I want to create a regex where I have these conditions:

1. String  top cannot have any alphabet (a-z) preceding or after adjacent to "top" like "laptop" and "topbest" respectively
2. String top can have any punctuation or special characters before or after it.
3. String top can have any special character or alphabets beside the adjacent positions means "abcd top xyz" (this is a match)

Till now what I have done is `[^a-zA-Z]top[^a-zA-z]`, but this is not fulfilling my conditions.

Comment: Have you tried with [`\btop\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yvPF5R/1)?

Comment: You regex seems to be enough from your conditions: https://regex101.com/r/yvubqJ/1 What it the issue?

Comment: yes horcrux you very much near. Actually I have missed another condition . Please check.

Comment: @subhajit Done. So `top` can have any number before/after it as well?

Comment: Yes Mistalis. It should match

Comment: Mistalis it is not matching my requierment. Horcrux's solution is matching , but it is not matching the updated condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative lookaround:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])top(?![a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: @subhajit: You'll find explanation here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that one fits your needs: https://regex101.com/r/ptYfA5/1

Pattern:
`\w*?\btop\b\w*`

Where the `\w` is a word-char a of any length (`*` quantifier) before and/or after "top". The `\b` means a word-boundary.

If you'd want to cover the leading numbers stuff, you could also write something like

`(^[0-9]+?\. *)?\w*?\btop\b\w*`

Greetings from germany.

Comment: Same but simpler is `\btop\b`

Comment: Sure it is, but the longer regex covers the OPs requirements explicitly. So of course you're right, it doesn't matter in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

In the regex you provided, you missed a uppercase on a `Z`:
 `[^a-zA-Z]top[^a-zA-z]` should be `[^a-zA-Z]top[^a-zA-Z]`

I would suggest to use:

```
[^a-zA-Z](top)[^a-zA-Z]
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/ptYfA5/3)

---

[*@horcrux*'s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133541/regex-for-string#comment75285679_44133541) to use `\btop\b` seems good as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this regex suits your need ?

> https://regex101.com/r/ptYfA5/5

```
.*(?<![a-zA-Z])top(?![a-zA-Z]).*

.*             ## match any characters before top
(?<![a-zA-Z])  ## negative lookbehind : check we don't have any [a-zA-Z] character before top
top            ## assert the string "top"
(?![a-zA-Z])   ## negative lookahead : check we dont have any [a-zA-Z] after top
.*             ## match any characters after top
```

Comment: `.*` are superfluous.

Comment: Toto can you please explain why ? I didnt understand . And one request can you please explain the metacharacters you have used in your solution . I will be highly oblidged. Thanks

Comment: @subhajit: Thre're no needs to test if there are 0 or more any character before and after. You just want to test `top` without letter before and after.

Comment: @Toto Quite true. Thanks for commenting =)